# Simple ways to interact with services?

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider

Are there some ways to interact with services as simple as content providers'?

I mean, for example with content providers we have [`getContentResolver()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver()): easy to query data if you have a [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). You even don't have to worry about the details of cross-process calls ([`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)).

With services, you have to bind them, wait for connection to be established, then make sure to unbind them if you don't want to leak the memory. Worse, you have to deal with [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) for remote services.

Taking this example:

I have a file downloader module. Currently there are two approaches: content provider or service. To start every new download, it is easy for both:

- Service: [`startService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)). You just need a context.
- Content provider: `getContentResolver()` and insert the new download into its queue. You also just need a context.

But while the downloads are in progress, I want to obtain some information (average speed, percentage done…). The problem is here: a content provider is more easier to communicate with. Again you just need a context and query the information you want. In case of a service, you need to bind it, unbind it, or build your own AIDL (if it's a remote service)…

I'm asking this question because with above example, a service seems to be the right approach over a content provider, at least because of its name.

Thanks,

Comment: What are you going to do with the "average speed", "percentage done" information?

Comment: @Squonk I want to display them in UI in case the user wants to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways I would suggest to do this...

The first is to try using [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) which implements `Parcelable`.

Basically create your own class which extends `ResultReceiver` then call `putExtra(String name, Parceable value` on an `Intent` which you pass in `startService(Intent intent)` from your `Activity`. The `Service` can then use `send(int resultCode, Bundle resultData)` on the `ResultReceiver` to send data back. If the `ResultReceiver` is an inner class of your `Activity` it will be able to interact with its UI.

The second possibility is to use `Notifications` using the `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` flag. This obviously wont appear in the `Activity` itself but will appear in the `Notification` bar but you can create a custom `RemoteView` with a progress and update text etc with each updated notification. This is similar to what you see when Google Play is installing or updating an app on your device.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you so much. You saved me a day with that `ResultReceiver`, especially it's available in API 3+. Thank you  :-)

Comment: Glad to help. I use `ResultReceiver` myself to communicate between a `Service` and an `Activity`. It works quite well.

Comment: @LaiVung : Also for downloads look at `IntentService` - it creates its own worker thread and will self-terminate once it has finished its work. See - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to rewrite some services to use `IntentService` too  :-D  There are lots of things to learn.

Comment: @LaiVung : A friend of mine once said "The fun is in the learning". That's why we do this stuff. Good luck and have fun. :)